# JAXB seems to be re-encoding new line char

Tags: java, encoding, jaxb

I have the following code...

```
public static final String NEWLINE = String.format("%n");
...
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
...
b.append(NEWLINE);
return b.toString();
```

However when I run this in SOAPUI and look at the RAW it looks like it is augmenting it again and the new line turns into

```
&#xD;
```

So instead of

```
<SOAPEnvelope>1,name,value
             2,name,value<SOAPEnvelope>
```

It shows up as...

```
<SOAPEnvelope>1,name,value&#xD;
             2,name,value&#xD;<SOAPEnvelope>
```

So when I parse using a regex query to replace  with an empty string the full text is still around

Now I am not as familiar with encoding but this is the payload of a SOAP message. The envelope is stripped away and this is ouputed to a CSV file. When I open the CSV in Notepad++ the new line char appears to work but that encoded value is still there. Does anyone know what I am missing?

I tried adding a (sb = Stringbuilder)

```
sb.append("<![CDATA[");
...
sb.append("]]>");
```

But this doesn't seem to work, again JAXB seems to escape the chars.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns4:ReportResult xmlns:ns2="http://me.com/v1_9/service" xmlns:ns3="http://me.com/v1_9/service/objects" xmlns:ns4="http://me.com/v1_9/service/operations">&lt;![CDATA[000000,LK20130930120048,Compant,Data,20130930120048,,&#xD;
000001,user,Fname,Mname,Lname,12345 Address 1,Address 2222,setAddress3,setCity,OH,US,44332,,N,N,E,,,,?,,&#xD;
999999]]&gt;</ns4:ReportResult></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Also I would be fine with something like [this](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/cdata-cdata-run-run-data-run.html) but I use the default marshaller for JAX-WS. So I am not exactly sure where to put it.

Comment: What do you mean by "augmenting it again"? It would really help if you'd show some input and actual output. That looks like an XML-encoded carriage return, which isn't particularly surprising in an XML document.

Comment: Right so I can't really post too much but I will try to expand my detail. Yeah I think that is what is going on as well I am just not good at encoding. So once I consume this I parse it to a file using perl and it seems to maintain the char (the value shows up instead of being just a carriage return). Let me know what other info will make it clearer.

Comment: Why can't you post sample data? It doesn't have to be a *real* file with important data in - just a couple of lines of "foo" and "bar" sort of data.

Comment: We don't properly obfuscate data is the main reason. But that is what I tried to do with those SOAPEnvelope examples. I will try to put together more but is there something in particular you are looking for? I will try to put together a gist soon.

Comment: Just because you don't obfuscate your *real* data surely doesn't stop you from coming up with *sample* data. To be honest, it's very hard to follow what you're doing at the moment - your sample code doesn't do anything with SOAP, for example. More description would really help, along with more code. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Ok I will work on that

Answer (score 4):

A JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will do the following:

- `\n` will be written to XML as a new line.
- `\r` will be escaped as `&#xD;`

### Demo Code

**Foo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    public String slashN;
    public String slashR;
    public String slashRslashN;

}
```

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.slashN = "Hello\nWorld";
        foo.slashR = "Hello\rWorld";
        foo.slashRslashN = "Hello\r\nWorld";

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <slashN>Hello
World</slashN>
    <slashR>Hello&#xD;World</slashR>
    <slashRslashN>Hello&#xD;
World</slashRslashN>
</foo>
```

Comment: Thanks man BTW I would like your slides from JavaOne because I got sick and missed your presentation. Anyway as you can see I am using the generic (%n) so is the \r coming from that? Do I need to use \n instead of String.format("%n")? Also will the \n still work once the CSV has been transferred to Windows? Basically right now they are just stripping the char in perl so I would like to avoid having to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the special character in a `<![CDATA[ ]]>`  block. It should avoid the re-encoding.